# Client DNS Records Not Updating Unless They Are Unsecure

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, window-server-2019

I have 2 member servers on my domain that are getting an event 8018 which looks like this:

> Log Name: System
> Source: Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client
> Date: 4/21/2016 10:57:23 AM
> Event ID: 8018
> Task Category: (1028)
> Level: Warning
> Keywords:
> User: NETWORK SERVICE
> Computer: Computer.domain.local
> Description:
> The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs)
> for network adapter
> with settings:
> Adapter Name : {58413179-8931-4FFB-9764-DD65696FCC74}
> Host Name : ComputerName
> Primary Domain Suffix : domain.local
> DNS server list :
> x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
> Sent update to server :
> IP Address(es) :
> x.x.x.x
>
> The reason the system could not register these RRs was because the DNS
> server contacted refused the update request. The reasons for this
> might be (a) you are not allowed to update the specified DNS domain
> name, or (b) because the DNS server authoritative for this name does
> not support the DNS dynamic update protocol.
>
> To register the DNS host (A or AAAA) resource records using the
> specific DNS domain name and IP addresses for this adapter, contact
> your DNS server or network systems administrator.

These 2 servers are joined to my domain and are in Active Directory. When I go to do an ipconfig /registerdns on these 2 servers I get this error. I went into my DNS server on my Domain Controller and set the DNS updates to Secure and Nonsecure. When I got back to the ipconfig /registerdns and then check the event log again it gives me an event 8012 saying that it couldn't update the PTR record but checking the DNS it shows the A record updated.

If these 2 servers are joined to the domain why are they not sending secure DNS updates for A records?

Comment: Are the computer accounts for these servers listed on the Security tab of the corresponding A record with Read, Write, and Special permissions? If not then delete the A records and run ipconfig/registerdns again after setting the zone back to secure.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes they are on the security tab. Problem is if I set it back to secure the records aren't made. And I get the permission error.